# jQuery and XML best way to parse

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

Trying to parse an XML result from a Web Service, vinquery.com, usually the values are in between the key name e.g. hello however the XML returned is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<VINquery Version="1.0.0" Report_Type="BASIC" Date="1/19/2012">
    <VIN Number="1ZVFT80N475337065" Status="SUCCESS">
        <Vehicle VINquery_Vehicle_ID="32627" Model_Year="2007" Make="Ford" Model="Mustang" Trim_Level="V6 Deluxe Coupe">
            <Item Key="VINquery_Vehicle_ID" Value="32627" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Model Year" Value="2007" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Make" Value="Ford" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Model" Value="Mustang" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Trim Level" Value="V6 Deluxe Coupe" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Manufactured in" Value="UNITED STATES" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Production Seq. Number" Value="337065" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Body Style" Value="COUPE 2-DR" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Engine Type" Value="4.0L V6 SOHC 12V" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Transmission-short" Value="5A | 5M" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Transmission-long" Value="5-Speed Automatic | 5-Speed Manual" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Driveline" Value="RWD" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Tank" Value="16.00" Unit="gallon" />
            <Item Key="Fuel Economy-city" Value="18 - 19" Unit="miles/gallon" />
            <Item Key="Fuel Economy-highway" Value="26 - 28" Unit="miles/gallon" />
            <Item Key="Anti-Brake System" Value="Non-ABS | 4-Wheel ABS" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Steering Type" Value="R&amp;P" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Standard Seating" Value="4" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Optional Seating" Value="No data" Unit="" />
            <Item Key="Length" Value="187.60" Unit="in." />
            <Item Key="Width" Value="74.00" Unit="in." />
            <Item Key="Height" Value="54.50" Unit="in." />
        </Vehicle>
</VIN>
</VINquery>
```

What is the most efficient way to obtain the value of say `Item Key="Body Style"` using `$(xml)` or other?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you've tried out jQuery's automatic bultin XML parsing and got performance problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery.parseXML() : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

```
   var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xmlstring);     
   $xml = $( xmlDoc );     
   $(xml).find("Item").each(function () {  
      if ($(this).attr("Key") == "Body Style")
      {
           alert($(this).attr("Value"));    
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute filter, in particular the attributeEquals filter:

```
$("node[Key='Bob Style']");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/ukahum/edit#javascript,html

```
var x='<VINquery Version="1.0.0" Report_Type="BASIC" Date="1/19/2012">\
    <VIN Number="1ZVFT80N475337065" Status="SUCCESS">\
        <Vehicle VINquery_Vehicle_ID="32627" Model_Year="2007" Make="Ford" Model="Mustang" Trim_Level="V6 Deluxe Coupe">\
            <Item Key="VINquery_Vehicle_ID" Value="32627" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Model Year" Value="2007" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Make" Value="Ford" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Model" Value="Mustang" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Trim Level" Value="V6 Deluxe Coupe" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Manufactured in" Value="UNITED STATES" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Production Seq. Number" Value="337065" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Body Style" Value="COUPE 2-DR" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Engine Type" Value="4.0L V6 SOHC 12V" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Transmission-short" Value="5A | 5M" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Transmission-long" Value="5-Speed Automatic | 5-Speed Manual" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Driveline" Value="RWD" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Tank" Value="16.00" Unit="gallon" />\
            <Item Key="Fuel Economy-city" Value="18 - 19" Unit="miles/gallon" />\
            <Item Key="Fuel Economy-highway" Value="26 - 28" Unit="miles/gallon" />\
            <Item Key="Anti-Brake System" Value="Non-ABS | 4-Wheel ABS" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Steering Type" Value="R&amp;P" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Standard Seating" Value="4" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Optional Seating" Value="No data" Unit="" />\
            <Item Key="Length" Value="187.60" Unit="in." />\
            <Item Key="Width" Value="74.00" Unit="in." />\
            <Item Key="Height" Value="54.50" Unit="in." />\
        </Vehicle>\
</VIN>\
</VINquery>';

alert($(x).find("Item[Key='Body Style']").attr('Value'));
```